# Query out features with value "x" from feature layer

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I can't figure out a way to return all features except ones containing a particular "fieldY = valueX"!  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To return all features except ones having a particular value, use something like fieldY <> valueX as in:

```
featureLayer.definitionExpression= "GRADE <> 'B'";
```

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#definitionExpression